# Adding a custom attribute to magento backend category pages on second category levels

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-attribute, programmatically

I am trying to display a custom attribute in the backend of magento on the category pages where the category levels are 2nd level.

I found an tutorial online which enabled me to add a custom attribute to the category pages. The code that I am currently using is:

```
require_once "app/Mage.php";

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;

$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label'=> 'Out of stock msg',
    'input' => 'text',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information"
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category.level', 'out_of_stk', $attribute);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Any ideas as to how I go about only applying this to second level categories? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do not bother that it is filled somewhere else.

Only use the values from level 2 you can simply find level 2 category by

```
// Walk categories
foreach ($product->getCategoryCollection() as $category) {
    // Find level 2 category
    while ($category->getLevel() > 2) {
        $category = $category->getParentCategory();
    }

    // If found, stop searching
    if ($category->getLevel() == 2) {
        break;
    }
}

$outOfStockMessage = '';
if ($category->getLevel() == 2) {
    // Set message from category
    $outOfStockMessage = $category->getData('out_of_stck');
}

echo $outOfStock;
```